# How to print the days of the week using a structure member?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I want to print the days of the week in this program but it doesn't work, what can I do to fix it ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct month{
    int date[12];
    char day[7];
}mon;
main()
{   int i;

    strcpy(mon.day[0],"Sunday");
    strcpy(mon.day[1],"Monday");
    strcpy(mon.day[2],"Tuesday");
    strcpy(mon.day[3],"Wednesday");
    strcpy(mon.day[4],"Thursday");
    strcpy(mon.day[5],"Friday");
    strcpy(mon.day[6],"Saturday");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("Day %d is %c\n",i+1,mon.day[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `strcpy(mon.day[0],"Sunday");` --- problem!!

Comment: The compiler should be shouting warnings at you. What is e.g. `mon.day[2]`? Is it really a *string* (which can be used as a destination for `strcpy`), or a *single character* (like you print it)?

Comment: `printf("Day %d is %c\n",i+1,mon.day[i]);
    }` => `printf("Day %d is %s\n",i+1,mon.day);
    }`

Comment: char day[7] - it is 7 chars. Not 7 strings, not 7 char pointers, nothing else. Just 7 chars (bytes). Also you do overflow everything in strcpy.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read e.g. [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function). Your declaration of `main` is invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wrong format changed. Mobile comment

Comment: the posted code has LOTS of undefined behavior.  starting with: the field 'day[]' is only 7 characters long and every string has a trailing NUL byte, so none of the strings: `Sunday` through `Saturday` will fit into that 7 characters.  The result of each call to `strcpy()` will always overflow the buffer, resulting in undefined behavior

Comment: OT: regarding:  `{   int i;`  It is poor programming practice to have more that one statement per line.  (always consider a opening brace '{' as the end of a statement)

Comment: OT: the `date[12]` field is never used, so why have it?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to store strings in `char`. However, a string is an array of `char`. Instead of this:

```
char day[7];
```

You need something such as:

```
char day[7][16];
```

Now you have 16 `char` to fit in a weekday, and you have that seven times, one for each day. Also, your print is wrong. To print strings, you need `%s`, not `%c`. `%c` is just for one single char:

```
printf("Day %d is %s\n", i + 1, mon.day[i]);
```

---

Another way of doing it is to have an array of `char*` instead of `char` and only storing the address of the strings rather than copying the strings:

```
char *day[7];
```

Then store the addresses like this:

```
mon.day[0] = "Sunday";
mon.day[1] = "Monday";
mon.day[2] = "Tuesday";
...
```

And print it the same way, with `%s`.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to compile your program, your compiler will give you certain warnings. Like

- **Problem 1:**

  ```
  source_file.c:10:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   main()
   ^
  ```

  The proper signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, for usual hosted environments.
- **Problem 2:**

  ```
  source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
  source_file.c:13:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       strcpy(mon.day[0],"Sunday");
       ^
  source_file.c:13:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
  source_file.c:13:5: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘strcpy’
  ```

  You'd need to include `string.h` header file which contains the declaration for `strcpy()`.
- **Problem 3:**

  ```
  source_file.c:13:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       strcpy(mon.day[0],"Sunday");
  ```

  This indicates, the first argument of `strcpy()` expects a `char *`, but you're passing a `char`, casted to an `int`.

  This is the most important point here, as you'd see, you need to pass a *buffer* which can contain the content from the copied string. Thu's, you'd need
- `day` to be a 2-D array
- use `day[i]` to store the content
- use `%s` to print the content thereof.

Answer (score 0):

For constants like day and month, better constructed like the following, unless you are practicing with struct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    const char *day[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
              //^^^^^ array of strings.
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("Day %d is %s\n",i+1,day[i]);
    return 0;
}
```